# How to line up jQuery deferred objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I need to delay every Ajax call until the previous function (`hashcode.Sign()`) has been completed. Unfortunately my code doesn't wait until `hashcode.Sign()` is completed and that messes everything up, since that function creates a new session and it cannot be overwritten in order to things to work. How should I do that? I'm new to Deferred objects so pardon my lack of knowledge.

```
    for (var l = 0; l < fileArray.length; l++) {
        var d = new jQuery.Deferred();
        d.resolve(openDdoc(fileArray[l].url, $pid, fileArray[l].id));
        d.done(function() { console.log('done'); });
    }

    function openDdoc(url, pid, fid) {
        var def = new jQuery.Deferred();
        $.when(def).done(function() { console.log('Function completed!'); });
        def.resolve($.ajax({
                    url: '/open-ddoc',
                    type: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    data: {doc: url, pid: pid, fid: fid},
                }).done(function (data) {
                    hashcode.Sign();
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    console.log('this shit failed');
                }));
    }
```

The `hashcode.Sign()` function includes some more Ajax calls and calls to other functions. I can include it later if neede. I know I could resolve all of this with `setTimeout()`, but that wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: Yes, please include `hashcode.Sign()`. It is important that it is written in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious but the sequentiality you seek can be expressed in the form of `fileArray().reduce(...)`.

This tried and tested pattern is outlined [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) under the subheading "The Collection Kerfuffle". (The whole article is well worth reading).

```
fileArray.reduce(function(promise, file) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/open-ddoc',
            type: 'post',
            async: true, // <<<<< always TRUE!!
            data: {doc: file.url, pid: $pid, fid: file.id}
        });
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(file.id + ': done');
        return hashcode.Sign(); // hashcode.Sign() must return a promise
    });
}, $.when()) // <<<<< resolved promise to get the chain started
.then(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

In this pattern, each member of `fileArray` is visited in turn (synchronously), adding a fresh `.then()` to a growing promise chain at each visit.

The resolved starter promise, `$.when()`, causes the constructed chain to start settling, and the ajax calls are made in sequence.

The ajax call doesn't need to be in a separate function, unless it's going to be called elsewhere.

**It should be emphasised** that `hashcode.Sign()` (which we understand to be asynchronous) must be written in the right way such that it returns a valid promise. If not, then the settlement process has no way of ensuring its asynchronism(s) to be complete before proceeding.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious, `// hashcode.Sign() must return a promise` is probably one of the more important points within this answer. If `hashcode.Sign()` doesn't return a promise, there isn't much you can do to fix this other than fixing `hashcode.Sign()` to return a promise.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks. Yes, obvious to you and me but maybe not the OP. I've added a footnote for now. When the OP responds to my request for the `hashcode.Sign()` code, I will be able to make a suitable edit. If you get there first, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for solid reply. I added the [corresponding function to PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dZS9BTED) for you to look at. At the moment I must admit, it's not returning promise.

Comment: `hashcode.Sign()` and `hashcode.hashCreateResponseHandler()` need some work. Both must return promises as must all inner functions that perform async actions. Also, `.done()` and `.fail()` don't possess the power to "filter" promises so you also need to change <most|all?> `.done(fn)` to `.then(fn)`, and `.fail(fn)` to `.then(null, fn)`.

Comment: I replaced `return hashcode.Sign()` with `return hashcode.Sign().then(function(res) { console.log(file.id+': done'); });`. Looking at the console, the subsequent AJAX calls to /open-ddoc are still made too early, before the first `hashcode.Sign()` gets everything done. But I get the general idea now. It seems the JS deferred and Promise patterns are just another nut to crack before I get my head around them. :) Thanks anyways!

Comment: You need a lot more returns. All functions, *including inner functions*, that perform something async must return a promise to inform their caller of the eventual outcome, very much like regular synchronous code. Fortunately, `$.ajax()` and `$.post()` both return a promise, so simply write `return $.ajax(...)` and `return $.post(...)`.

Comment: If a promise is not returned, then an async activity is nothing more than a side effect that does not contribute to the settlement of the overall promise chain.